# How do I attach an existing <IMG> element (HTMLImageElement) to a Facebook React.js component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an IMG DOM element I generated with a data-uri. How can I attach it to the React.js "virtual DOM"?

When I try the following:

```
myImgComponent = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    slowGenerateImage((function(_this) {
      return function(img) { /* img is an HTMLImageElement */
        return _this.setState({
          image: img
        });
      };
    })(this));

    return {image: null};
  },

  render: function() {
    return div(
      {}, 
      this.state.image /* image is a raw HTMLImageElement */
    );
  }
});
```

I get the following error:

```
Invariant Violation: traverseAllChildren(...): Encountered an invalid child; DOM elements are not valid children of React components.
```

Answer (score 5):

Could you instead just render `<img src={this.state.img.src}/>`? Or even have `slowGenerateImage` just generate the `src`, not create an element, then you can pass that through directly.

Comment: I tested this and it does work. I suspect the first option results in the browser decoding the image twice. Thankfully I do control the source library so I can make a version that returns a dataUri instead of a full IMG object.

Comment: The browser probably doesn't decode twice unless slowGenerateImage actually inserts the img element into the document.

Comment: I use system.js `import image from './image/source.png!image` and just use the image.src like you mention

Answer (score 4):

This is seems like a bad thing to do, but...

Usage:

```
return <DomNode node={someDomNode} />;
```

---

Note: the below is outdated, as pointed out by **@sookie**. In newer versions, you use ReactDOM.findDOMNode, and class syntax.

---

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/hepeboke/2/edit?js,output

Code:

```
var DomNode = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function(){
    this.updateNode(this.props.node);
  },
  componentWillRecieveProps: function(nextProps){
    if (nextProps.node !== this.props.node) {
      this.updateNode(nextProps.node);
    }
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function(){
    this.updateNode(null);
  },
  updateNode: function(node){
    var myNode = this.getDOMNode();
    for (var i=0; i<myNode.children.length; i++) {
      myNode.removeChild(myNode.children[i]);
    }

    if (node) {
      myNode.appendChild(node);
    }
  },
  render: function(){
    return <div />
  }
});
```

Note: this does insert an extra div, I don't know if there's a way around that but I don't think there is.

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping for a more general escape-hatch for adding in DOM nodes generated by external libraries. Though I'm new to React, I believe your solution is safe as long as the DOM nodes generated are stateless.

I cracked open the React source, and I agree, it's probably not possible to remove the extra div. We could change the kind of tag that is generated, but React appears to assume it is generating a fresh DOM node from a markup-string. The key bit of code appears to be "mountComponent: Initializes the component, renders markup, and registers event listeners.".

Comment: Note: getDOMNode() is deprecated in React 0.13 and above. We must now use `react-dom`'s `findDOMNode()`

Comment: @sookie thanks, added a note. Some of my answers are older than vampires...